# How to export some value at the place of image to csv and pdf using <display> tag?

Tags: displaytag

I have a jsp containing following code:

```
<display:table onclick="myAction.do?method=displayDetails" sort="list" name="${UCForm.liste}" defaultsort="1" defaultorder="descending"
pagesize="40" export="true" requestURI="myAction.do?method=recherche"
decorator="web.displaytag.TableDecorator" id="listeId">
<display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="abc.csv" />
<display:column property="abcName" title="Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"/>
<display:column title="VL" sortable="true" headerClass= "sortable" >
<c:if test="${listeId.blocagevl eq 1}"><img src="img/Lock.png" height="10" width="10"/></c:if></display:column>
</display:table>
```

When I am exporting this to csv, first field i.e name is exporting correctly but for second field which is an image whole image tag `<img src="img/Lock.png" height="10" width="10">` is exporting to csv file.

What I want is to export true if image is present and false if its not or any value that I wish.
I am trying this from last 3 days but didn't find any solution.

Comment: you don't want image tag in export ?

Comment: No. I want some text at its place.

Answer (score 0):

you can use media attribute of column tag as below :

```
<display:column title="VL" sortable="true" headerClass= "sortable" media="html" >
    <c:if test="${listeId.blocagevl eq 1}"><img src="img/Lock.png" height="10" width="10"/></c:if>
</display:column>
<display:column title="VL" sortable="true" headerClass= "sortable" media="csv" >
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${listeId.blocagevl eq 1}">
              true
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise >
              false
        </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>      
</display:column>
```

Read [Configuring export and export views](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/export.html) link.